# Selecting $M:$M and $N:$N returns "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are a different size"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've simplified the code below for readability, after verifying that the other parts of the code do work. When I select a specific range, it works, but selecting the entirety of the M and N columns said that there are different array sizes.

I've checked the range, and both have their last cells at the same mark, so I'm not sure what the issue may be.

Please let me know if there's anything that is sticking out to you :)

```
=countifs("New Leads!"$M:$M), NameCell,"New Leads"!$N:$N),Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct syntax:

```
=COUNTIFS('New Leads'!M1:M, "NameCell", 'New Leads'!N1:N, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: well, "NameCell" was a placeholder for something like B2, so no quotes BUT I refreshed the page today and it's working now so... I wonder if there's a term for ghost errors.